# popup working properly in jquery mobile 1.4.0?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

I am creating a popup when one process is complete and before changing the page popup not showing.My code is

```
 <div data-role="popup" id="confirm" data-overlay-theme="none" data-theme="none" style="max-width:100%;background:url(images/alert-bg.png) repeat-x;" class="ui-corner-all">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="none" class="ui-corner-top warning-border">
                <h1 style="color:#fff;font-size:14px;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">Warning</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="main" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
                <h3 class="ui-title alert" style="color:#fff;font-size:16px;font-family:'Nova Square', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:400;"></h3>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-mini="true" data-transition="flow" data-theme="a" style="background-color:#fff !important;color:#4f72b3;">OK</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

and call the popup like

```
 $("h3.alert").html("");
 $("h3.alert").append("User is alerady Exist");
 $("#confirm").popup();
 $("#confirm").popup("open");
 $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', '#enroll-screen', {
                        transition: 'pop',
                       changeHash: false,
                        reverse: true,
                        showLoadMsg: true
                    });
```

but not showing the popup? how to solve this issue

Comment: are you calling _popup_ right before page change? it won't appear. it will be closed once `pagebeforechange` is triggered. you should change  page after popup is closed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/YLn6C/ check this

Comment: Also, you do not need to do this ".pageContainer.pagecontainer" as now all widgets that are inside a page will get auto initialized. Same with this "$("#confirm").popup();" See here.  http://jsfiddle.net/85RSU/

Answer (score -1):

you right html and js but which page you want popup at this page inside content only you put your html code.
**for ex:**

```
 <div data-role="page" id="indexpage">
 <div>header</div>
   <div>content
//here paste your popup html code`
  </div>

  <div>footer</div>
 </div>
```

Note:when showing index page at the time only showing this popup. you want all pages means you need to append html dynanically